# How to calculate the arc length of a cardioid-like (the innerloop)?

Tags: integration, parametric, arc-length

I'm trying to calculate the arc length of the innerloop see picture of a cardioid-like $r=4a\cos^3\frac\theta3$ but don't know where to start. I know you have formulas like $L=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{r^{2}+\left(\frac{d r}{d \theta}\right)^{2}} d \theta$, but don't know how to do this for the innerloop.

thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Send the actual equation

Comment: $4 (x^2+y^2-a x)^3=27 a^2 (x^2+y^2)^2$ with $a = 20$

Comment: Your formula is in polar coordinates, while the equation you sent is in rectangular coordinates and looks quite hard to convert in polar

Comment: Just find the range of $\theta$ and apply the formulas.

Comment: @TheCreator: there is a typo in this equation.

Comment: $r=4 a \cos ^{3}\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ this is the polar form

Comment: so does my alpha and beta needs to be my x coordinates of A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take out constants and multiply them back in at the end, so the curve is $r=\cos^3\frac{\theta}3$.

The required length is twice the length of the curve from $\theta=\pi$ to $\theta=\frac{3\pi}2$. Thus
$$\frac L2=\int_\pi^{3\pi/2}\sqrt{\cos^6\frac\theta3+\cos^4\frac\theta3\sin^2\frac\theta3}\,d\theta$$
$$=\int_\pi^{3\pi/2}\sqrt{\cos^4\frac\theta3}\,d\theta=\int_\pi^{3\pi/2}\cos^2\frac\theta3\,d\theta=\frac34\left(\frac\pi3-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$$
Therefore the length of the inner loop for $r=4a\cos^3\frac\theta3$ is $a(2\pi-3\sqrt3)$.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but what is then your theta in $r=4 a \cos ^{3} \frac{\theta}{3} \text { is } a(2 \pi-3 \sqrt{3})$? $\pi$ or $(3\pi)/2$?

Comment: @TheCreator The arc length was asked for, so there is no $\theta$.